# "Unknown class ABC in Interface Builder file" AND "This class is not key-value compliant..."

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am attempting to set some properties of my ViewController via the User Defined Runtime Attributes section in XCode and running in to a few issues.

Firstly when the ViewController is instantiated (by a segue in my storyboard) I get the following in the output window:

> Unknown class FlyoutViewController in Interface Builder file.

Secondly, I get the following error:

> Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSUnknownKeyException Reason: [UIViewController 0x7fdc1450> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key topViewControllerStoryboardId.

I have read the [troubleshooting guide](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/troubleshooting/) and nothing helped. The only part that stood out for me was:

> the types containing the above code must be a subclass of NSObject

Although I fail to see how that is possible when subclassing UIViewController?

For reference here is the relevant parts of my code:

```
[Register("FlyoutViewController")]
public partial class FlyoutViewController : UIViewController, IUIViewControllerContextTransitioning, IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator, IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext
{
    public FlyoutViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) 
    {
       // Stuff here
    }

    [Export("topViewControllerStoryboardId:", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
    public NSString TopViewControllerStoryboardId { get; set; }

    [Export("underLeftViewControllerStoryboardId:", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
    public NSString UnderLeftViewControllerStoryboardId { get; set; }

    [Export("underRightViewControllerStoryboardId:", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
    public NSString UnderRightViewControllerStoryboardId { get; set; }

    // More stuff...
}
```

In the properties of the ViewController in the storyboard I have set the class to `FlyoutViewController` and added the following runtime attributes:

> topViewControllerStoryboardId | String | FeedNavigationController
>   underLeftViewControllerStoryboardId | String | MenuViewController

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't solve your problem, but I can tell you that the second error is caused by the first: when it doesn't know what a `FlyoutViewController` is, it instantiates a `UIViewController` instead. But then it moves on, trying to set `topViewControllerStoryboardId` on it, which predictably doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks @andyvn22 that makes sense. If only I could now find out why it doesn't recognise my subclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are implementing two interfaces that have at least two identical members: 
`IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext` and `IUIViewControllerContextTransitioning`.

This is the output I am getting, *prior* to the "...this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key topViewControllerStoryboardId" message:

> Cannot register more than one interface method for the method
>   'XcodeAttrController.MyController.get_ContainerView' (which is
>   implementing
>   'MonoTouch.UIKit.IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext.get_ContainerView'
>   and
>   'MonoTouch.UIKit.IUIViewControllerContextTransitioning.get_ContainerView').

Note that my controller here is named "MyController" :).

Implement one of the interfaces in another object and use that one instead.

Comment: You are 100% correct, thank you! Although I'm not sure how I can change the implementation, given that I am already implementing `UIViewController`. I guess I need to subclass one of the interfaces that use `ContainerView`, and then use that class as a child property of `FlyoutViewController`. Does that sound the most logical thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the view controller was only included in one of the build targets, and the program crashed when the program for the target that did not include the view controller crashed.